# How to cut specific number without cut all numbers

Tags: cut

```
F gge0006y

D 12-30-2006

T 14:05:55

S a69

B 15.3

M gge06001

P 30.6

Q 21.1

R 1006.6

U 1014.6

X 36.1

A 38.994        0             0

G 107.71        0             0

H 8.433

O 36.705

C 7.621

K 27.623

W 210.51
```

I need to cut the both 0           0 
from A and G but I cant seem to do it without cutting all zeros from the text 
which is not what I want, just those four zeros, how would I do this?

Comment: probably has flaws but `sed 's/ 0//g' input` or `sed 's/0             0//g' input` <=SE removed the extra spaces in there.

Comment: What's the rule? "Remove columns 2 and 3 if they exist?" or " ... if they exist and are 0"?  or "if they exist on lines where column 1 is an A or G"?

Comment: @cargoboom:  Be wary of using my first suggestion.  if any of your numbers start with a 0 it will give unwanted results. For example if you had: `C 07.621` it would cut it to `C 7.621`

Comment: Rather than cutting the fields you *don't* want, consider printing the fields that you *do* e.g. `cut -d ' ' -f1,2 file` or `awk '{print $1, $2}' file`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *input* is space delimited:

```
cut -d' ' -f 1-2 input
```

(This answer is the same as [*steeldriver*'s prior comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423419/how-to-cut-specific-number-without-cut-all-numbers/423444#comment762628_423419)...)